# jQuery Set attr and then Get attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a page that sets 2 attributes and then I am trying to reference those attributes after the page has loaded.

I have been able to set the attributes without a problem, I have also been able to reference the attributes if I hard code them into the credit and debit attributes.

But trying to call them dynamically isn't working. Open to suggestions.

```
<div class="net" credit="" debit=""></div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    ... some fancy code involving arrays and junk ...
    if(TYPE == 'credit') {
        $(".net").attr('credit',data.response.stats.total);
    } else if (TYPE = 'debit') {
       $(".net").attr('debit',data.response.stats.total);
    }
});

$(window).bind("load", function() {
    afterPageLoad();
});

function afterPageLoad(){
    total_credit = $(".net").attr('credit');
    total_debit = $(".net").attr('debit');
    total = (total_credit - total_debit);
    $(".net").html( "$"+total );
}
```

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8m3Gh/1/ though I would recommend using `.data()`

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: You should use `parseFloat();` when grabbing the attributes for credit and debit

Comment: Thanks guys, .data() is a much better way. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest using `data-` attributes that can be read by jQuery.data()

```
<div id="test" data-foo="bar"></div>
```

GET

```
alert( $('#test').data('foo'))
```

SET

```
$('#test').data('foo','new value, or object or array'))
```

The attributes don't have to exist to use this. You can store anything any time on an element, as well as read data in markup.

[**jQuery.data() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the *"... some fancy code involving arrays and junk ..."*

`data.response` suggests you are making an Ajax call which is asynchronous and you are trying to read the attributes before they are set.

Put the logic in the callback of the Ajax call, do not call in the onload portion.

Comment: This also helped, thanks man. It does mean that I call the afterPageLoad() a few times but I thought the document ready and the document load actually meant that they would happen before and after the page loads!

Comment: Yeah, but that does not mean it waits for the Ajax requests to load, it is only the document.

Comment: Again, thank you. You're the best viking that I have ever spoken to.

Answer (score 0):

To read dynamic attribute values, you need to use `prop()` instead of `attr()`.

Ideally, however you should store custom values in a `data-` attribute (i.e. `data-credit`) and then use jQuery's `data()` method to get/set the value.

Answer (score 0):

When grabbing the attributes for `total_credit` and `total_debit` you should use `parseFloat();`

ex: `parseFloat( $(".net").attr('credit') );`

you should also set a fallback in the case the attribute isn't set.

ex: `total_credit = parseFloat($(".net").attr('credit')) || 0;`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var TYPE = 'credit';
    if(TYPE == 'credit') {
        $(".net").attr('credit', 123);
    } else if (TYPE = 'debit') {
       $(".net").attr('debit', 53);
    }
});

$(window).bind("load", function() {
    afterPageLoad();
});

function afterPageLoad(){
    total_credit = parseFloat($(".net").attr('credit'))||0;
    total_debit = parseFloat($(".net").attr('debit'))||0;
    total = (total_credit - total_debit);
    $(".net").html( "$"+total );
}
```